# What level of measurement can I use to compare a student's different test scores?

Tags: normalization, measurement

Let's say a student takes multiple different tests. I get a percentage for each of the test scores (the tests have a different amount of multiple choice questions, and the multiple choice questions are all different across tests).

What level of measurement can I use to compare these different percentages?
Is it ordinal, interval or ratio?

This other post [Measurement level of percentile scores](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/928/measurement-level-of-percentile-scores) suggests that it should be interval. However, my question is different as there are different "questionnaires".

Does having different sources for the percentages affect anything?

Comment: What would be the practical effect of choosing a "level of measurement"?  What do you hope that would accomplish?

Comment: I'm hoping to justify what ways I can compare test scores by just looking at them.